# Swift Package containing multiple binary frameworks (that wrap a C library)

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to build a Swift package containing multiple binary xcframeworks (each of which wrap a different static C library). The .xcframework contains multiple versions of the same library (one per arch type - x86_64, aarch64). I first build the static library for each arch, and then, create the .xcframework with

```
xcodebuild create-xcframwork -library /path/to/lib_for_arch1 -headers /path/to/headers -library /path/to/lib_for_arch2 -headers /path/to/headers -output MyXcFramework.xcframework
```

The headers folder above contains the header and a module.modulemap file.

When adding two such binary frameworks to a single Swift package, I get a build error

```
Showing All Messages
duplicate output file ‘/Path/To/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh/Build/Products/Debug/include/module.modulemap' on task: ProcessXCFramework /Path/to/BinaryFramework1.xcframework /Path/to/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh/Build/Products/Debug/include/module.modulemap macos


Showing All Messages
Multiple commands produce '/Path/To/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh/Build/Products/Debug/include/module.modulemap':
1) Command: ProcessXCFramework /Path/To/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh/SourcePackages/artifacts/MySwiftPackage/Framework1.xcframework /Path/To/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh//Build/Products/Debug/include/module.modulemap macos
2) Command: ProcessXCFramework /Path/to/BinaryFramework1.xcframework /Path/To/Xcode/DerivedData/MySwiftPackage-djghajsghjsgsjdgh/Build/Products/Debug/include/module.modulemap macos
```

As best as I can tell, while processing each binary xcframework, it's copying the contents of each xcframework's `Headers` folder into the `include` folder of the package. When it's copying the second module.modulemap, it errors out because one already exists (from the first binary xcframework).

I've tried wrapping each binary xcframework inside a Swift package of it's own, and making my primary Swift package depend on these wrapper packages instead. But, I still get the same error.

Any ideas on what the best way forward would be? Thanks

P.S. Using Xcode 12.5.1 and Swift 5.4.2

Edit: Using a Xcode project (that embed two binary xcframeworks similar to the above setup) instead of Swift package, results in the same error as well.

Comment: Same problem here - can you try to include the .xcframeworks directly in your project?

Comment: @ineiti I've tried including the .xcframeworks directly in a xcode project (outside of a package), and, also, as local binary frameworks in a package. Both end up with the same issue. I've posted my current workaround as an answer, but, am hoping there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work by doing the following. Assuming, we are creating two binary frameworks (CLib1.xcframework and CLib2.xcframework - each wrapping a C library). We are going to use these frameworks in a Swift package `MySwiftPackage`

1. Create the wrapping xcframeworks (CLib1 and CLib2) without the headers and module.modulemap. `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library /path/to/lib1`
2. Setup binary targets in the Swift package MySwiftPackage that pull in these frameworks
3. Add a include directory in the main targets of MySwiftPackage. Add the headers of CLib1 and CLib2 to this folder.
4. Create a single custom module.modulemap which setups modules for both CLib1 and CLib2. Save it in the include folder.
5. Add `csettings` to the target on MySwiftPackage. Set the `headerSearchPath` to the include folder

While this builds, I'm hoping there is an easier/better way to do this (as removing the module.modulemap from the xcframework's means we always have to custom create one - and it no longer is just a simple import of a binary framework).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the headers and the `module.modulemap` in another subdirectory than `headers`, like `lib1` and `lib2`.

As the example shows, it is important to chose a directory that is not used by another library. So the library-name is a good choice.

Then you can run the following:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library ... -headers ...
```

And it *should* pick up the headers.

Comment: If the normal location for A.xcframework is A.xcframework/macos_arm64/Headers, I should put it in A.xcframework/macos_arm64/Headers/A ? Wouldn't this requiring editing the Info.plist in the root of the xcframework as well? Can we change the location using "xcodebuild -create-xcframework", or do we do this manually? Thanks

Comment: In fact you can put the headers wherever you want, and then run `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library ... -headers ...`. There is no need to put `Headers` in the path.

Comment: Could you clarify this @ineiti? When I run: `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library lib/libapriltag.a -headers include/apriltag -output ./Clibapriltag.xcframework` it results in an XCFramework with Clibapriltag.xcframework/iOS-arm64/Headers/module.modulemap. When I build in Xcode, that module map gets copied into `include` in my build folder where it conflicts with another XCFrameworks's module map built the same way.

Comment: I don't remember anymore how I did it, but it seems strange that the `module.modulemap` goes into a directory called `Headers` - I'll check the arguments again...